# To find duplicate entry in c++ using 2D Vector (std::vector)

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I wrote a program to find duplicate entry in a table. I am a beginner in `C++`, hence I don't know how this program is working efficient. Is there any other idea to write this program? Here I have 3 tables (2D Vector), that they are 1)`aRecord_arr` 2)`mainTable` and 3)`idxTable`. `idxtable` is use to identify the keys to check duplicate entry. `aRecord_arr` table to be add in `maintable`. If it is already exist in `maintable`, it will show the error "Duplicate Entry". So Check this program, and give your suggestions.

```
typedef vector<string> rec_t;
typedef vector<rec_t> tab_t;
typedef vector<int> cn_t;
int main()
{
    tab_t aRecord_arr=  { {"a","apple","fruit"},
                          {"b","banana","fruit"} };

    tab_t mainTable =   { {"o","orange","fruit"},
                          {"p","pineapple","fruit"},
                          {"b","banana","fruit"},
                          {"m","melon","fruit"},
                          {"a","apple","fruit"},
                          {"g","guava","fruit"} };

    tab_t idxTable = { {"code","k"},
                       {"name","k"},
                       {"category","n"}};

    size_t Num_aRecords = aRecord_arr.size();
    int idxSize = idxTable.size();
    int mainSize = mainTable.size();

    rec_t r1;
    rec_t r2;
    tab_t t1,t2;
    cn_t idx;

    for(int i=0;i<idxSize;i++)
    {
        if(idxTable[i][1]=="k")
        {
            idx.push_back(i);               
        }
    }

    for(size_t j=0;j<Num_aRecords;j++)
    {
        for(unsigned int id=0;id<idx.size();id++)
        {
            r1.push_back(aRecord_arr[j][idx[id]]);
        }
        t1.push_back(std::move(r1));
    }

    for(int j=0;j<mainSize;j++)
    {
        for(unsigned int id=0;id<idx.size();id++)
        {
            r2.push_back(mainTable[j][idx[id]]);
        }
        t2.push_back(std::move(r2));
    }

    for(size_t i=0;i<t1.size();i++)
    {
        for(size_t j=0;j<t2.size();j++)
        {
            if(t1[i]==t2[j])
            {
                cout<<"Duplicate Entry"<<endl;
                exit(0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code not work? Or is it just slow? Or are you asking for alternative methods?

Comment: I need alternative method. My question is, is this program efficient or not?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid duplicate entries in an array, you should consider using a `std::set`instead.

Comment: You re-phrased it so that it sounds more like an answer. That's perfectly OK with me. :-)

Comment: Okay ; I'm kind of new here, so I'm still learning; thanks, I'll keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably a std::map or a std::set 
Don't reinvent the wheel, the STL is full of goodies.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be rooted in a weakly typed language - but C++ is strongly typed. 
You will 'pay' the disadvantage of strong typing almost no matter what you do, but you almost painstakingly avoid the advantage.
Let me start with the field that always says 'fruit' - my suggestion is to make this an enum, like:

```
enum PlantType { fruit, veggie };
```

Second, you have a vector that always contain 3 strings, all with the same meaning. this seems to be a job for a struct, like:

```
struct Post {
    PlantType kind;
    char firstchar;
    string name;
    // possibly other characteristics
};
```

the 'firstchar' is probably premature optimization, but lets keep that for now.

Now you want to add a new Post, to an existing vector of Posts, like:

```
vector<Post> mainDB;

bool AddOne( const Post& p )
{
    for( auto& pp : mainDB )
        if( pp.name == p.name )
            return false;
    mainDB.push_back(p);
    return true;
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
if( ! AddOne( Post{ fruit, 'b', "banana" } ) )
    cerr << "duplicate entry";
```

If you need speed (at the cost of memory), switch your mainDB to map, like:

```
map<string,Post> mainDB;

bool AddOne( const Post& p )
{
    if( mainDB.find(p.name) != mainDB.end() )
        return false;
    mainDB[p.name]=p;
    return true;
}
```

this also makes it easier (and faster) to find and use a specific post, like

```
cout << "the fruit is called " << mainDB["banana"].name ;
```

beware that the above will cause a runtime error if the post dont exists

As you can see, `firstchar` was never used, and could be omitted.
 std::map
has a hash-function-specialization for string keys, and it will probably be
orders of magnitude faster than anything you or I could whip up by hand.

All of the above assumed inclusion of the correct headers, and

```
using namespace std;
```

if you dont like `using namespace`, prepend `std::` to all the right places
hope it helps :)